# How to create files and directories in Kotlin?

Tags: android, directory, kotlin

I've been trying to create a simple path with Kotlin in Android Studio, but unfortunately I am unable to do so. 
Right now, my code looks like this:

```
lateinit var context : Context

private const val PERMISSION_REQUEST = 10

fun makeDir(){
    // I/O logic
    val filename: String = "ziemniakList.txt"
    val myDir: String = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString() +  "/Ziemniak/"
    // create a File object for the parent directory
    val sciezka = File(myDir)
    // have the object build the directory structure, if needed.
    sciezka.mkdirs()
    // create a File object for the output file
    //val outputFile = File(sciezka, filename)
    //println("makeDir!")
    Toast.makeText(context, myDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}

class NowaDostawa() : AppCompatActivity() {

private var permissions = arrayOf<String>(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nowa_dostawa)
    var MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1

    context=this

    val menuLista = arrayOf("Online", "Gotówka", "Karta")
    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, menuLista)
    spinner.adapter = adapter


    buttonNoweZamowienie.setOnClickListener{
        if(inputAdres.text.toString() == "" || inputKwota.text.toString() == ""){
            Toast.makeText(this, "All the fields needs to be filled!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            var allSuccess = 1
            for(i in permissions.indices){
                if(checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permissions[i]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    allSuccess = 0
                }
            }
            if(allSuccess == 1){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Permissions granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                makeDir()
                finish()
            }
            else{
                requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST)
            }
        }
    }

}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST){
        var allSuccess = true
        for(i in permissions.indices){
            if(grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                allSuccess = false
                var requestAgain = shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[i])
                if(requestAgain){
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Permissions hasn't been granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Set permissions by yourself!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }
        }
        if(allSuccess){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Permissions has been granted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            makeDir()
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

So basically, when I hit 'buttonNoweZamowienie' button, the folder should create under /data/Ziemniak/, but it doesn't. As you can see, I grant the permissions and it works good, but i still find it hard to create some basic directory. What might be the problem? If there are some things I haven't specified, feel free to ask

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm curious. What's your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: @es0329 minSdkVersion 19

Answer (score 0):

[Read is implicitly permitted when write is granted.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

Have you also declared the permission in the app's manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Yes, I did declare it. And I agree, I have to remove write permission

Answer (score 0):

**Don't forget to add this in you AndroidManifest.xml**
`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`